# How to commit sqlalchemy db session after storing file on localstorage

Tags: flask

I am trying to create an api which will allow to upload image and store in static folder inside project for now and send html url of that image file to db and store it in a table.

Also, if possible on a side tip, can you tell me this is a good approach ?

Currently I can upload image to static/images/ folder in project and print downloadable file url. But can not send that to db and store it.
below is my code:

```py
class img_details(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    short_description = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=False)

    def __init__(self,
                 img_url,
                 ):
        self.img_url = img_url


class userDataSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = img_details
    id = ma.auto_field()
    img_url = ma.auto_field()
    description = ma.auto_field()
    short_description = ma.auto_field()


user_data = userDataSchema(many=True)

# enable CORS
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origin': '*'}})


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify({'in': 'progress'})


@app.route('/user_image', methods=["POST"])
def user_image():
    if 'uploaded_file' not in request.files:
        return jsonify(({'message': 'No file in the request'}))

    input_file = request.files['uploaded_file']
    filename = secure_filename(input_file.filename)
    input_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    uploaded_img_file_url = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
    # print(uploaded_img_file_url+ " "+file_hosting_url)

    description_value = request.json['description']
    short_description_value = request.json['short_description']
    file_hosting_url = request.root_url + url_for('download_file', name=filename)

    uploaded_img_file_path = img_details(img_url=file_hosting_url, description=description_value,
                                         short_description=short_description_value)
    db.session.add(uploaded_img_file_path)
    db.session.commit()
    #return jsonify({'message': str(request.root_url + url_for('download_file', name=filename))})
    return jsonify({'message': 200})
```

[image]

Comment: Your approach is fine. What's the error you are receiving ?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>

Comment: Not that one. I meant the error from the console..

Comment: I am using postman to upload

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are using on the frontend. How do you launch your application? There should be some kind of error *where* you launched your application.

Comment: on flask i get"127.0.0.1 - - [30/Apr/2023 14:19:15] "POST /user_image HTTP/1.1" 400 -" when i perform post call. other than that when i start server i dont get any error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253402/discussion-between-venkat-g-and-bck).

Comment: resolution: i should be using request.form instead of request.json when posting form content.
help provided by - @BcK

Answer (score 0):

resolution:
I should be using request.form instead of request.json when posting form content. help provided by - @BcK